# port problems for not being root

Tags: ros, xsens, permission

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm working with a xsense-mti with [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/lse_xsens_mti) node. I can run it perfectly as a root if i type: su, the pasword and then I go to the bin folder in the package and run ./mti_node

The thing is that when I try to run rosrun lse_xsens_mti mti_node I cannot connect to the port. How can I change it? If I can not run it as a normal user I can not launch it from a file with the rest of nodes I'm inerested!

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12821/port-problems-for-not-being-root/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are missing permissions on the device.
The easiest might be to add yourself to the dialout group as in most cases that's where it is. Otherwise you need to setup udev rules.

What does `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*` and `id -a` give you?

I use this udev rule for xsens:

```
# xsens FTDIs with product id d38b
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="d38b", SYMLINK+="sensors/ftdi_%s{serial}", MODE="0666", GROUP="dialout"
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on 2015-11-14**:
if i `ls - l /dev/ttyUSB*` and the result is  `No such file or directory`.
and `id-a` gives :
`uid=1000(adelleodel) gid=1000(adelleodel) groups=1000(adelleodel),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)`what to do?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-16**:
This is a different problem. Please open a new question and describe, what you are doing.